# com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/plain. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, integration-testing

Hello I am trying to create a dirty test for my soap integration test. I just got SSL working on my spring boot app and I wanted to see if it will hit my soap end point.

When I run man verify on my integration test I get this error:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/plain. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
```

Here is my test code :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {EndPointTestConfiguration.class
})


public class SoapIT {
private static ApplicationContext context;
    @BeforeClass
    static public void  setup(){
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplicationBuilder()           
                .sources(MockServerApp.class)
                .build();
        context = springApplication.run();
    }


    @Autowired
    private String studyDetailDemo;
    @Test
    public void soapTest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = Request.Post("https://127.0.0.1:28443/nulogix/ws/billingtool")
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(studyDetailDemo, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();

    }
}
```

I am kind of new to integration testing and have no idea what this error means

Thank you for any help

Comment: You are sending the request as plain text, that is what the `ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN` is. Instead you should be sending a content type of XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up a bit on how to do spring testing.

[testing-with-mock-environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment)

`@SpringBootTest` will automatically scan for spring annotated classes and load up a mockspringcontext for you so you dont need to do all the `@BeforeClass` things.

If you want to call this "Mock context" you need configure and autowire in a MockMvc, WebTestClient or TestRestTemplate.

On the other hand if you want to start a real server you need to specify `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` (or a defined port).

You can read all about it in the linked documentation above.

And btw, you can't autowire in a string.

Your code should look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SoapIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private String studyDetailDemo = "some body text";

    @Test
    public void soapTest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = Request.Post("https://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/nulogix/ws/billingtool")
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(studyDetailDemo, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();

    }
}
```

Havn't tried the code, wrote it on mobile.